# Titanium studio cannot run "titanium" command in terminal

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I tried to run "titanium" command in terminal of Titanium studio but it gives following error

```
$ titanium
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.1, Titanium SDK version 3.1.1.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/

[ERROR] "c:\Users\grant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\bin\titanium" is an unrecognized command.

Run node.exe help for available commands.
```

I'm running Titanium studio on Windows 7. I can run "titanium" command successfully on windows cmd and it gives the expected output. I'm very new to Titanium studio and according to my knowledge all paths are configured correctly. I can create and run Titanium projects on Android emulator.
What can be caused for the error please help me.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same situation here today. After some Google search, I found out that it's actually a bug in Titanium Studio. See [this ticket](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-14074).

In the comments, you can find [a fix in a Github pull](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium/pull/44/files). You can apply the fix manually and it should work(worked for me on my Windows7).

BTW, the file is located at `%appdata%\npm\node_modules\titanium\lib\cli.js` in case you are wondering.